# Check if directory exists

Tags: vba, excel

I have this piece of code, but can't make it run for it returns `Bad file name or number error` :

```
If Dir(ws.txtFldr, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Output Directory does not exist!", vbExclamation, "Error!"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

I just want to check if the given directory exists, if not, then prompt the message. `txtFldr` is an activeX textbox control and `ws` is a worksheet. I'm actually saving it in either a shared dir or just local.

Comment: What type of activex control it is (txtFldr) ?  Seems to be improper usage

Comment: @Sixthsense a textbox

Comment: What is the exact value of ws.txtFldr when you put a break point on it and check?

Comment: @braX This one `\\10.249.10.2\data$\Test\08.08.17\Test`

Comment: Do you have access to that folder? What happens if you paste that into just a regular explorer window? (not Internet explorer window)

Comment: @braX Ohhh! This returns an error message :S, needs permission

Comment: So fix the permissions, there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: @braX Weew, its part of an administrative security, but do you know any workaround for it?

Comment: No, you cannot bypass administrative security settings.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
If Len(Dir(ws.txtFldr, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Output Directory does not exist!", vbExclamation, "Error!"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Many other ways are also shown by doing a search on the internet. For example, [here](https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?157-Function-To-Check-If-File-Or-Directory-(Folder)-Exists) it has another approach:

```
Public Function FileFolderExists(strFullPath As String) As Boolean
'Author       : Ken Puls (www.excelguru.ca)
'Macro Purpose: Check if a file or folder exists

    If strFullPath = vbNullString Then Exit Function
    On Error GoTo EarlyExit
    If Not Dir(strFullPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True

EarlyExit:
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Public Sub TestFolderExistence()
'Author       : Ken Puls (www.excelguru.ca)
'Macro Purpose: Test if directory exists
    If FileFolderExists(ws.txtFldr) Then
        MsgBox "Folder exists!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Folder does not exist!"
    End If
End Sub
```

This second approach is using some the `Error` handling functionality available in VBA and `GoTo` labels to bypass code.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried this approach, it gives the same error.

Comment: Sure. I see in the comments to your question that the value being passed might be the culprit.

Comment: Accessing the directory through that is disallowed, do you know any work around for it?

Comment: No. Out of interest, if you were to map that network drive to a drive letter and use the drive letter path instead does it work?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You can usually map network paths to virtual drive letters. So instead of `\\10.249.10.2` it could become, for example, `x:\\`